# iOS Game Engine Choice

Tags: ios, 3d, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

I'm very new to iOS game development but I've worked a bit on iOS apps and had my fair share of Objective-C. I already have the concept for my game planned out but I'm not sure if I'll need a 2D engine or a 3D engine. The closest example I can give to how the possibly-3D part of the gameplay will be is Clash of Clans, where there are buildings that look 3D, but you never turn around them or anything, you just see people or my character walking between them with the possibility of zooming in and out and panning. I'm kind of inclined to use Cocos2D since it seems very easy and documented but I want something worth it at the end, something that won't limit me someday if I want to create a proper game or expand the one I'm working on.

So should I go with 3D or 2D development and what engine or development environment should I go with if so?

Comment: If you're thinking "Clash of Clans", then you're planning to build   a **3D game with a two-dimensional playing field**. You'll need a 3D engine to render the graphics (Cocos2D will not do). I'm not going to try and convince you that you should do something else, but be aware that all other things being equal, game development is much harder for 3D than 2D.

Comment: I'm very open to learning whatever it is I need, so it's fine if Cocos2D won't do...what will though in the case of a "3D game with a two-dimensional playing field"? And this might be a stupid question but does learning 2D game development give a headstart in learning 3D development?

Comment: It's really hard to cover such a broad question in a comment, but building a 3D game means you have to think about additional things like camera parameters and 3D geometry for your characters. If you've never built a game before, starting off with a 2D game will definitely be easier. And learning good game design strategies should carry over from 2D to 3D. However, whatever time you invest in learning a particular 2D engine may not carry over to a different 3D engine.

Comment: Yeah, you're right...I'll probably learn something like Cocos2D first then. When I do get into 3D though, should I delve into OpenGL or go with a Flash-like engine?

Comment: Cross that bridge when you come to it :)

Comment: @RahulBanerjee From my research, I guess, COC is a perspective or pseudo-3D view based game. 

But non of the commercial or existing game engines will let you build the game easily. You might have to put lot of effort in build a special purpose Engine for this purpose. Some topics you might have to familiarize with Batching rendering in OpenGL before you can achieve similar visuals and animations.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know if you'll need a 2D or 3D engine, the by definition your game concept is not planned out. ;)

Whether you need 2D or 3D is really up to you.

If you worry to be limited by the game engine, pick one that's open source. That way you can make any changes yourself. Though you should not overestimate the time and effort required to make changes to an engine, because that often requires intimate knowledge of the inner workings of the engine.

I have more [general advice for picking a game engine here](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/05/the-game-engine-dating-guide-how-to-find-the-right-engine-for-your-game/). Best advice is to pick an engine **you** can be most productive with rather than picking an engine based on its feature set - unless you have requirements that are absolutely non-negotiable (such as 3D rendering).

Comment: That was a great read, really...it did put me on the right track and for that, I thank you. I still don't know if my game requires 3D rendering or not though. Could you help me decide that referring to the Clash of Clans example?